# How to add pe:badge to dynamically created menu in bean using PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I’m rewriting static menu to dynamic, since our customer wants to dynamically change the menu on the fly. Before that I had standard <p:menu> <p:menuItem> </p:menu> structure in my xhtml.

But now I have changed it to:
`<p:menu model="#{pageTemplateView.menuModel}"/>`

And I’m creating model in my backing bean like this:

```
DefaultMenuItem menuItem = new DefaultMenuItem();
menuItem.setIcon(item.getIcon());
menuItem.setTarget(item.getLink());
menuItem.setValue(item.getName());
```

But the problem is I don’t know how to add `<pe:badge>` component inside menu item from bean.

Before that I included badges to menus the following way:

```
<p:menuitem id="tasks_icon_menuitem_id" icon="fa fa-tasks" url="#">
  <pe:badge content="#{badgeCountBean.badgeCount()}"/>
</p:menuitem>
```

So how do I add `<pe:badge>` to dynamically created menu in bean?

I'm using PrimeFaces 8

Comment: You could try using the `for` attribute. Note that the badge is deprecated in PFE 10.

Comment: I am not sure we tested it for MenuItems either?

Comment: Hey I have tryed using `for` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Melloware no, it was initially only working for buttons, but I removed that constraint to be able to use it on avatars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few hours of testing and plying around I found the issue that prevents me from adding badge to default menu item.
The issue is when you try to add child to `DefaultManuItem` like this:

```
Badge badge = new Badge();
DefaultMenuItem defaultMenuItem = new DefaultMenuItem();
defaultMenuItem.getChildren().add(badge);
```

You get unsupported operation exception since DefaultMenuItem:: getChildren() is implemented like this:

```
public List<UIComponent> getChildren() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

But I have found an ugly workaround for this issue. So I might share it and maybe well get to better solution eventuality.
In my xhtml I added empty menu and gave it fixed ID like this:

```
<!-- MENU PLACEHOLDER -->
<p:menu id="dynamic_menu_placeholder"/>

<!-- need to add dummy badge to xhtml otherwise it wont be displayed -->
<pe:badge/>
```

And then in my bean I got the component by ID and added `UIMenuItem` elements to it like this:

```
// get component by ID
UIComponent component = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(":form:dynamic_menu_placeholder");
Menu menu = (Menu) component;
menu.getChildren().clear();

for (MenuItem item : menuItemList) {

    // creating menu item
    UIMenuItem menuItem = new UIMenuItem();
    menuItem.setUrl(item.getLink());
    menuItem.setValue(item.getValue());
    menuItem.setId(... generated some id);
    
    // creating badge
    Badge badge = new Badge();
    badge.setContent(...getBadgeCount()..);
    
    // adding badge to menu item
    menuItem.getChildren().add(badge);
}

// addin menu item to menu
menu.getChildren().add(menuItem);
```

Comment: as a note if you are moving to Primefaces 10 you should use the PF Core Badge and not the PFE Badge as its being removed in 10.0.1 now that PF has a real Badge component.